# Custom position of Actionbar Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, android-actionbar-tabs

Is there way how to set custom position of  Actionbar Tabs? Or set the layout like in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use ActionBar Tabs. They are deprecated in Lollipop and on.

> This class was deprecated in API level 21.

You should be using [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) inside of the design support library.

```
compile "com.android.support:design:'24.0.0'"
```

TabLayout gives you the freedom to put it anywhere inside of the layout.

This is a pic of the example below:

[image]

**Here is an example**

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Header Layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#7DC476"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/someView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="88dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Some View 1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="#CCFFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!-- For a single list -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerVIew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <!-- For a pager list -->
    <!--<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/pager"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
    <!--app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />-->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/someView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#7DC476"
        android:elevation="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Some View 2" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabLayoutExample extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout_example);
        hideSystemUI();
        initTabs();
        initRecycler();
    }

    private void initTabs() {
        TabLayout mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
        mTabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Toast.makeText(TabLayoutExample.this, "Tab " + tab.getPosition() + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void initRecycler() {
        List<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        ExampleAdapter exampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(listData);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerVIew = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerVIew);
        mRecyclerVIew.setAdapter(exampleAdapter);
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            listData.add("Android " + i);
        }
        exampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
        private List<String> list;

        public ExampleAdapter(List<String> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ExampleViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            ExampleViewHolder exampleViewHolder = (ExampleViewHolder) viewHolder;
            exampleViewHolder.bindData();
        }

        public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            protected TextView mText;

            public ExampleViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                this.mText = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            }

            public void bindData() {
                String dataItem = list.get(getAdapterPosition());
                mText.setText(dataItem);
            }
        }
    }

    // Ignore, just for removing systemUI bars(Full Screen)
    private void hideSystemUI() {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```